# What does "Scan advances the Scanner to the next token" mean in Go's bufio.Scanner?

Tags: go

According to [`Scanner.scan documents`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner.Scan), `Scan()` **advances the Scanner to the next token**, but what does that mean? I find that `Scanner.Text` and `Scanner.Bytes` can be different, which is puzzling.

This code doesn't always cause an error, but as the file becomes larger it does:

```
func TestScanner(t *testing.T) {
    path := "/tmp/test.txt"
    f, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprint("failed to open ", path))
    }
    defer f.Close()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)

    bs := make([][]byte, 0)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        bs = append(bs, scanner.Bytes())
    }

    f, err = os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprint("failed to open ", path))
    }
    defer f.Close()
    scanner = bufio.NewScanner(f)
    ss := make([]string, 0)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        ss = append(ss, scanner.Text())
    }

    for i, b := range bs {
        if string(b) != ss[i] {
            t.Errorf("expect %s, got %s", ss[i], string(b))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The token is defined by the scanner's [split function](https://godoc.org/bufio#SplitFunc). Scan() returns when the split function finds a token or there's an error.

The String() and Bytes() methods both return the current token. The String() method [returns a copy of the token](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/2d86f4942868c1309051062237cf4d424d588e9c/src/bufio/scan.go#L107). The Bytes() method does not allocate memory and [returns a slice](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/2d86f4942868c1309051062237cf4d424d588e9c/src/bufio/scan.go#L101) that may use a backing array that's overwritten on a subsequent call to Scan().

[Copy the slice](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks#copy) returned from Bytes() to avoid this issue:

```
for scanner.Scan() {
    bs = append(bs, append([]byte(nil), scanner.Bytes()...))
}
```